# Asciidoc inserting Gitlab builder variables when creating the adoc file?

Tags: gitlab, asciidoc

Good day all, been reading the various docs at **Gitlab** and **Asciidoc** websites and I'm not seeing if there's a way to autofill a variable created in **Gitlab** that is included in the **asciidoc** it creates? For example, if I'm pushing code to my branch and it starts the **Gitlab** builder. I would like to take the author variable with my name in it and when the **asciidoc** that the builder generates, can I just put **{author}** for it to auto-fill my name in it?

Not 100% sure I'm understanding how this works exactly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Gitlab builder explicitly calls `asciidoctor`, you can define attributes using the `-a` flag. For example:

```sh
asciidoctor -a author="My Name" contents.adoc
```

Environment variables can be added in the same way:

```sh
asciidoctor -a author="My Name" -a path=$PATH contents.adoc
```

See the [CLI Options page](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/cli/man1/asciidoctor/#options) for other options that you can specify during `asciidoctor` invocation.

If the builder calls other actions that do the building, and you cannot access those actions, then this won't work.

Note that defining the page author is normally handled by including the name (and email address) immediately after the page title (before the first blank line). See the [Using the Author Line page](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/document/author-line/) for details.

For example:

```
= Document
Author name
```

The standard Asciidoctor theme automatically displays the page author immediately after the page title.

For other attributes that are included in the document, or specified as page attributes, you'd need to include `{attribute_name}` within the page markup to see them.